# Magento 2 - join using EAV attribute

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

I created an EAV attribute on product entity, this attribute named `user_id` and has the ID of the user who's added the product.

After works, I crashed on this point, I need to join tables to get products added by a specific user.

So, I try with this code

```
->join(
      array(
           'product' => 'catalog_product_entity'),
           'product.user_id = 2',
            array()
      );
```

but always I get this error `Unknown column 'user_id'`

is there any solution?

Comment: what is the type of this EAV attribute? int|text|varchar|

Comment: @vitoriodachef int type

Answer (score 0):

Late in the party but whoever is seeing this nowadays: you need to explicitly add your custom attribute to the collection, then filter it, like that:

```php
$userProducts = $this->productsCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(["user_id"])
    ->addAttributeToFilter("user_id", 2);
```